# robots.txt handling a # in a URL

Tags: regex, robots.txt, noindex

Given the following URLs:

- example.com/products
- example.com/products#/page-2
- example.com/products#/page-3
- ...

By using the robots.txt file, the first URL (example.com/products) is supposed to be indexed, every other one should be blocked from being indexed. How can this be done?

None of the following attempts work in the desired manner:

- `Noindex: /products#/page-*`
- `Noindex: /products\#/page-*`
- `Noindex: /*/page-*`
- `Noindex: /*#/page-*`
- `Noindex: /*\#/page-*`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about SEO, not programming. Try [sf] or [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1):

`/products#/page` is not a unique page. The actual url is simply `/products`.

`#` is abused to hook into javascript frameworks that dynamically load other pages, but, but normally `/products#/page` means that your `/products` page has an element such as this `<a name="#/page">`, and you can't block specific elements.

SPA's break the web. You're better off creating real, independent pages.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after `#` is called "anchor". This information is NOT transferred to the server, hence you cannot read it from PHP, or any other language that is executed on the serverside.

As @Evert Outlines, the "anchor-tag" is commonly abused with javascript, as it can be modified WITHOUT the need of an actual redirect, allowing to generate  deep-links, for dynamic content. (They are working, cause a client-side javascript will take care to use AJAX to dynamically load content based on the anchor-tag)